# Delete objects directly from gc.get_objects?

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

There is a memory leak and it is not the real problem. :) The problem is just deleting the objects.
I can find the objects using `gc.get_objects` but how do I delete them?
I tried using del but it appears to be deleting the new reference. I want to delete that object completely.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, not yet. Will update you.